# C# Windows Forms KeyDown event fires continiously

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard-shortcuts

In a Windows forms application I'm trying to execute some function when I press a hotkey using Form's KeyDown event. The problem is that when I keep the hotkey pressed the event fires continuously.

I just want to execute some function at the first time I press the button and another function when I release it.

Here is the code I used to accomplish this operation:

```
    bool isPressed_Num7 = false;
    bool isPressed_Num9 = false;

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.NumPad7 && !isPressed_Num7)
        {
            isPressed_Num7 = true;
            Console.WriteLine("Keydown 7");
        }

        if (e.KeyData == Keys.NumPad9 && isPressed_Num9)
        {
            isPressed_Num9 = true;
            Console.WriteLine("Keydown 9");
        }
    }

    private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.NumPad7)
        {
            isPressed_Num7 = false;
            Console.WriteLine("Keyup 7");
        }

        if (e.KeyData == Keys.NumPad9)
        {
            isPressed_Num9 = false;
            Console.WriteLine("Keyup 9");
        }
    }
```

I'm going to use a bunch of hotkeys. So what I'm asking is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: [how not to allow multiple keystokes received at one key press?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490771/how-not-to-allow-multiple-keystokes-received-at-one-key-press)

Comment: If only we knew what you're trying to do.

Comment: I *think* what he's trying to ask is: how do I not end up with a variable for every key that has to be set to true and false in the event handlers.

Comment: try using `Keypress` instead of `Keydown`, as `Keydown` event loops as long as the key is Held Down.

Comment: @aquinas That's exactly what I was trying to do.

Comment: @Niklas That did not work, KeyPress event does exactly the same thing with KeyDown event.

Comment: @MoustafaMemet then try handling your key in your event on the keydown code you already have using e.Handled=true; see if it changes what you expect.

Answer (score 2):

You could just a dictionary instead of one variable per key.

```
Dictionary<Keys, bool> keysPressed = new Dictionary<Keys, bool>();


private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   keysPressed[e.KeyData] = false;
}

private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if (!keysPressed.ContainsKey(e.KeyData) || !keysPressed[e.KeyData]) {
         Console.WriteLine(e.KeyData);
         keysPressed[e.KeyData] = true;
   }
}
```

Comment: That's a cool solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 bool isPressed_Num7 = false;
bool isPressed_Num9 = false;

private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.KeyData == Keys.NumPad7) && (!isPressed_Num7))
    {
        isPressed_Num7 = true;
        Console.WriteLine("Keydown 7");
    }

    if ((e.KeyData == Keys.NumPad9) && (!isPressed_Num9))
    {
        isPressed_Num9 = true;
        Console.WriteLine("Keydown 9");
    }
}

private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.KeyData == Keys.NumPad7)&&(isPressed_Num7==true))
    {
        isPressed_Num7 = false;
        Console.WriteLine("Keyup 7");
    }

    if ((e.KeyData == Keys.NumPad9)&&(isPressed_Num9==true))
    {
        isPressed_Num9 = false;
        Console.WriteLine("Keyup 9");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses the recommended way to handle keyboard shortcuts according to Microsoft. And allows you to assign action to invoke when pressing a key combination.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly IDictionary<Keys, Action> _operationsMap = new Dictionary<Keys, Action>(); 

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        RegisterKeyShortcuts();
    }

    private void RegisterKeyShortcuts()
    {
        _operationsMap.Add(Keys.Control | Keys.F, WhenPressingF);
    }

    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (_operationsMap.ContainsKey(keyData))
        {
            _operationsMap[keyData].Invoke();
            return true;
        }

        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }

    protected void WhenPressingF()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("What the Ctrl+F?");
    }
}
```

Comment: What the Ctrl+F