# How to stop multi Ctrl+S until save process complete

Tags: c#, winforms

I have form to enter customer details when i press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save details and keep pressing it the keypress and key down event continuously fires cause duplicate record entry. Is there a way to let these fire only after my save process complete.

I found same question in blow link
[how not to allow multiple keystokes received at one key press?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490771/how-not-to-allow-multiple-keystokes-received-at-one-key-press)

I have check its solution but it’s not working for me I have to press multi times <kbd>S</kbd> KEY

Here is my code:

```
private void FrmAddBase_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
            if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.N)
            {
                if (btnAdd.Enabled)
                {
                    btnAdd_ItemClick(null, null);
                }
            }
            if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
            {
                if (btnSave.Enabled)
                {
                    btnSave_ItemClick(null, null);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Add a flag IsSaving?

Comment: What you can do is to unsubscribe to the event (KeyDown) when the event is trigger. Then you subscribe again after you process the event.

Comment: You don't seem to have implemented any of the answers in the link you gave

Comment: @o_weisman i have check it's solution but i have to press multi times S key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one comment pointed out you can just add a flag, somthing like this:

```
bool IsSaving;
private void FrmAddBase_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.N)
        {
            if (btnAdd.Enabled)
            {
                btnAdd_ItemClick(null, null);
            }
        }
        if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
        {
            if (btnSave.Enabled)
            {
                if(IsSaving) return;
                IsSaving = true;
                //I guess this is the save process, and its not threaded
                btnSave_ItemClick(null, null);
                IsSaving = false;
            }
        }
```

}